# Search box in ruby on rails not displaying results

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, search

I'm working with Ruby on Rails, trying to get my search bar to display the results. I've tried searching for similar issues, but most already had search working and weren't getting it to work right.

in my html I have:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<div class="scrollBox">
  <%= will_paginate%>       
  <ul>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to user.name, user, {:class=>"signout-style"} %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
 <%= will_paginate %>
</div>
```

In my users controller I have:

```
  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @searches = User.search(params[:search])
  end
```

In my users model I have:

```
 def self.search(search)
   if search
     find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
   else
     find(:all)
   end
 end
```

I was using the railscast episode #37
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please indent your code properly.. that minimum effort you should do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `index` action as below:

```
def index
  @users = User.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Currently, you are storing the search results in instance variable `@searches` with this line:

```
@searches = User.search(params[:search])
```

BUT in your view you are accessing `@users` which is set as `@users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])`. So, you always see *all the users* in the view and *not the searched users*.

**UPDATE**

As you are using `Rails 4.0.2`, I would suggest you to refactor your `search` method as below:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an undefined method error "
NoMethodError in UsersController#index
undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0xb557bb3c>"

Comment: @user3597710 What is the rails version you are using. Also, the version of `will_paginate` gem.

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.1.0 and the will_paginate gem is 3.0.4

Comment: @user3597710 What is your `Rails` version?

Comment: Thank you! I would totally upvote if I could, don't usually use stackoverflow

Comment: No Problem. Appreciate the thought. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit That will just make the code tighter by reducing the number of lines BUT the current code is more readable and easier for newbies to understand.

Comment: Ruby's expressiveness gives the freedom of doing the same thing in multiple ways. In this case I preferred to go for readability rather than compact code. BTW, doesn't ternary does the same thing(if/else..) internally. I think comments are getting lengthy unnecessarily as the OP's question is resolved. Appreciate the alternative you suggested.